# Array.set is not a function and cannot be applied

Tags: arrays, function, ocaml

I need to make a function which turns a random pixel in a picture to black. 
A picture is represented as an array of colors represented as Black or White. 
Here is my code :

```
type color = Black | White
;;

type picture = color array array
;;

let rec color_rand_point (img : picture) : picture =
  let randx = ref (Random.int (Array.length img))
  and randy = ref (Random.int (Array.length img)) in
  if (img.(!randx).(!randy) = White)then
    begin
      Array.set img.(!randx) (!randy) Black;
    end
    img
  else
    color_rand_point(img)
;;
```

Here is the result I have when I try compiling :

```
                  Lines 5-7, characters 4-7:
5 | ....begin
6 |       Array.set img.(!randx) (!randy) Black;
7 |     end
Error: This expression has type unit
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
#
```

I'm pretty sure the answer would be obvious to anyone knowledgeable about ocaml and that it's bad style, but I'm working on this as a student and have close to no idea about what i'm doing with ocaml. We didn't learn the basics in depth so I would like a simple answer if possible.

I have no idea of why Array.set isn't considered as a function applicable in an imperative bloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message doesn't point to `Array.set`, but to the `begin ... end` block, which evaluates to `unit` because `Array.set`, the only expression inside the block, returns `unit`.

The problem is that `img` is outside the block, and not separated by a semicolon, so you're effectively telling the compiler to pass `img` as an argument to whatever the `begin ... end` block evaluates to. Which is `unit`, not a function, as the error message says.

The error can be fixed just by moving `img` inside the block.

Comment: Or removing img. If the function modifies the original image then why should it return it? Returning an image would suggest a new image is created and the original left unmodified.